# Attempting to join on two dataframes based on multiple keys but getting error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of unequal sizes they both have two columns 'CUSIP' and 'Counterparty' that I am trying to match. I only want to take two column values from one dataframe, thus when I do this

```
df = df.merge(gs[['Dirty Price','Factor']], how = 'left', on = ['CUSIP', 'Counterparty'])
```

I am getting this error:

```
    df = df.merge(gs[['Dirty Price','Factor']], how = 'left', on = ['CUSIP', 'Counterparty'])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6868, in merge
    copy=copy, indicator=indicator, validate=validate)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 47, in merge
    validate=validate)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 529, in __init__
    self.join_names) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 833, in _get_merge_keys
    right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1706, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'CUSIP'
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Any ideas please share.

Comment: `gs[['Dirty Price','Factor']]` means you don't have these columns - `'CUSIP', 'Counterparty'` in it. Then how would the merge be possible? You should merge them and then filter out the columns you need.

Comment: as @CavinDsouza has said,  the double brackets returns a dataframe, change to `gs[['Dirty Price','Factor','CUSIP', 'Counterparty']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `CUSIP` nor `Counterparty` in your `gs` slice, try:

```
df = df.merge(gs[['CUSIP', 'Counterparty','Dirty Price','Factor']], how = 'left', on = ['CUSIP', 'Counterparty'])
```

Comment: I made a post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347810/joining-multiple-dataframes-together-and-making-sure-the-right-numbers-go-to-the. I think you may know what I am doing wrong if you could take a look?