# Joining multiple dataframes together and making sure the right numbers go to the same column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a few dataframes that all have a "Dirty Price" and "Factor" that I want to have in the same column. When I try to do this what happens when I join the second dataframe together then pandas creates a new "Dirty Price_x" and "Factor_x" but I don't want new columns I want them to me merged into the same column that match the criteria I specify.

This is what I did:

```
df = df.merge(gs[['CUSIP', 'temp_Counterparty','Dirty Price','Factor']], how = 'left', on = ['CUSIP', 'temp_Counterparty'])
df = df.merge(nomura[['CUSIP', 'temp_Counterparty','Dirty Price','Factor']], how = 'left', on = ['CUSIP', 'temp_Counterparty'])
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are looking to have multiple rows for each combination of Dirty Price and Factor from each dataframe, then you will have duplicated indexes, is that a probelm?

Comment: @jcaliz I am not sure, from an excel perspective I am simply trying to just vlookup the dirty price and factor such that the temp_counterparty and CUSIP are a match. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jcaliz The dataframe df has a temp_counterparty and CUSIP that match to the gs, and nomura dataframes. Perhaps that provides more context.

Comment: Yeah that is mostly what merge is normally used for, the question is, you have these two columns in `gs`, so they are saved in `df` on the first merge, and then you are looking to merge these columns again from `nomura`, so pandas will create the columns with the suffixes, my question is: are `Dirty Price` and `Factor` from gs equal in both `gs` and `nomura`?

Comment: @jcaliz No the Dirty Price and Factor from gs and nomura are different although for Factor there may be some that are the same. That should not matter since I am joining on their temp_counterparty (aka: "Goldman" or "Nomura") and CUSIP (which is just some id string)

Comment: Then the merge is doing the right thing, you are joining by index, and you have in the last data frame, a column for `Dirty Price` in `gs, another for `Dirty Price` in `nomura` that shares the same `CUSIP` and the same `temp_Counterparty`. The same applies for `Factor`, do you absolutely need these in the same column as different rows?

Comment: @jcaliz Yes, they should be in the same column. I am really trying to just duplicate something done manually in excel aka the vlookup. I just want to have the Dirty Price and Factor on the same column that corresponds to the CUSIP and temp_Counterparty. Maybe I am not explaining this well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `gs` and `nomura` do not share the same combination of `CUSIP` and `Counterpary`, you can concat these two dataframes and then do the merge

```
df_concat = pd.concat([ gs[['CUSIP', 'temp_Counterparty','Dirty Price','Factor']] , 
                        nomura[['CUSIP', 'temp_Counterparty','Dirty Price','Factor']]
                      ], axis = 0)


df = df.merge(df_concat, how='left', on=['CUSIP', 'temp_Counterparty'])
```